# Finding given price way on neo4j

Tags: neo4j, shortest-path

I have been developing an app for finding a path would cost under the given price among international flights with neo4j database. The response time of the query exists below took about 8 min. The database approximately comprises 17 nodes and 200 relationships between them. Why does it take much longer than usual?

```
MATCH (strt:Airport {code:'ATH'}) WITH strt as s
MATCH nodes = (s:Airport)-[rs:Leg *]->(other:Airport)-[:Leg]->(s:Airport)
WHERE not other = s and 200 > reduce(totalPrice = 0, r IN rs | totalPrice + r.price) and ALL(idx in range(0, size(rs)-2) WHERE (rs[0]).date = 201800408210000 and (rs[idx]).date = (rs[idx+1]).date +3000000 )
WITH *, reduce(totalPrice = 0, r IN rs | totalPrice + r.price) as tp
RETURN collect(distinct nodes), tp
ORDER BY tp DESC
```

Comment: Did you try using e.g. [`EXPLAIN`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unfortunately, It couldn't respond.

Comment: Can you describe more fully your data model and use case? Your current code is certainly not very efficient, but it is not clear what you are trying to do and how your data is arranged. (For example, why are all legs always supposed to be separated by exactly 50 minutes?)

Comment: An EXPLAIN of the plan should finish, even if a PROFILE does not. If the query can execute to completion, please provide the result from PROFILE. Otherwise, please provide the plan from EXPLAIN (with all elements of the plan expanded)

Comment: @cybersam There are 17 airports stored as nodes and 200 flight ticket with the price connected nodes each other as a relationship. We collect all the routes under the given price limit by us.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I got an empty response.

Comment: I don't uderstand this part : `MATCH nodes = (s:Airport)-[rs:Leg *]->(other:Airport)-[:Leg]->(s:Airport)` With this pattern, you are computing all the path of your database ... that why it takes times (200^18 is a big number ...)

Comment: @logisima It should check all the possibilities along paths until it exceeds price limit. That's why it checks all the nodes and legs. I am not sure is it efficient way or not.

Comment: It's not the efficient way to do it in Neo4j. You should considerer to write a custom procedure that execute a Graph Traversal.